# How to generate a matrix of random numbers using the normal distribution in AMPL?

Tags: cplex, ampl

How can I generate a matrix of random numbers using the normal distribution in AMPL with mean and variance listed below?

```
param mean :=
1   45
2   35
3   40;

param variance :
    1       2       3 :=
1   1      -2      -1
2  -2      36      -8
3  -1      -8       9;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMPL supports some random number functions for your parameters. 
You can try something like this:

```
 param matrix {x in dimx, y in dimy} 
          = Normal(mean[x], variance[x, y]);
```

If you want to make sure to get only positive numbers, you should wrap the Normal function with the max function.

```
max(Normal(mean[x], variance[x, y]), 0);
```